# Vector for bullet direction XNA C#

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, vector

im creating a platform shooter. the gun can be rotated using the thumbsticks. i want to use a line of fire `newBullet.bulletVel` variable as a Vector 2. this variable will be used to send the bullet in the direction that the barrel of the weapon is pointed at. How could i do this?

for gun rotation i have declared a float named rotation and use spritebatch.draw method to show that the variable is for rotation of the image.

```
public float WMrotation;

public void UpdateMe(GameTime gameTime)
    {                                 
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Right.Y < -0.1)
        {
            WMrotation += 0.03f;
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Right.Y > 0.1)
        {
            WMrotation -= 0.03f;
        }          
    }

public void DrawMe(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        sb.Draw(WMtxr, WMpos, null, Color.White, WMrotation, WMorigin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
```

ive set the bullet position when fired to be at the tip of the gun.

```
newBullet.bulletPos.X = player1.playerPosition.X + 15;
newBullet.bulletPos.Y = player1.playerPosition.Y + 15;
```

i think i need to use `newBullet.bulletVel` to calculate the vector in which the bullet travels

```
newBullet.bulletVel = i don't know what to put in here
```

[image: Diagram of desired vector]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use trigonometry:

```
x = cos(angle)
y = sin(angle)
```

Make sure angle is in radian